# Adding an object in a function in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to add some objects when a user clicks on a different object. The below code does not work. I also tried adding setCoords, but that did not seem to do anything.
Interestingly enough, the remove works as I intended.
Thanks for any advice

```
var showerOn = 0; //0 == off 1 == on
var sprayOption = 0; 
var massageOption = 0;
var trickleOption = 0;

function selectShower() {
  if(showerOn == 1) {
    showerButton.fill = 'yellow';
    canvas.add(showerSpray);
    canvas.add(showerMassage);
    canvas.add(showerTrickle);
  }
  else {
    showerButton.fill = 'white';
    showerSpray.fill = 'white';
    showerMassage.fill = 'white';
    showerTrickle.fill = 'white';
    sprayOption = 0; 
    massageOption = 0;
    trickleOption = 0;
    canvas.remove(showerSpray);
    canvas.remove(showerMassage);
    canvas.remove(showerTrickle);
  }
}

showerButton.on('selected', function() {
  showerOn = 1 - showerOn;
  selectShower();
  canvas.deactivateAll();
});
```

Comment: where are you initializing and/or resetting the `showerOn` variable to 1 or 0? Could you post the full script? I think this variable is either uninitialized or set incorrectly..

Comment: I initialize the variable right above the function. I'm just learning javascript and fabric.js, but from my understanding the showerButton.on makes the showerOn variable 1 the first time it is clicked, 0 the next time, and so on.

Comment: When you say this does not work, do you mean that the on('selected', callback) never occurs? You can try to debug this if using Google Chrome (F12). You can also put a `console.log(showerOn);` statement as the first line in `showerButton.on` to see if it is being fired.

Comment: try doing a `canvas.renderAll()` after you add the elements in the first `if` block...

Comment: By "doesn't work" I mean it does not add the objects. It is definitely goes into that if statement properly.
The canvas.renderAll() does not fix it either.

Comment: we are missing important part of code to understand what is going on.